# creating a dictionary with two tensors tensorFlow

Tags: python-3.x, tensorflow, tensor

I have two tensors

```
top_k_values = [[0.1,0.2,0.3] 
                [0.4, 0.5,0.6]]
top_k_indices= [[1,3,5] 
                [2, 5,3]]
```

I want to take the indices and the values and create dictionary like

```
dict[1] = 0.1   
dict[2] = 0.4    
dict[3] = 0.2 + 0.6   
dict [5] = 0.3 + 0.5
```

I want to order this dictionary by key and then select the top 3 indices
Could someone please help me. 
I have been trying to use map_fn. But this does not seem to be workin

Is the above problem solvable with tensorflow

Answer (score -1):

You can use a counter to accumulate the values for each indice. This is from python standard library. I don't know if you can do the same with tensorflow library.

```
>>> from collections import counter
>>> d=Counter()
>>> for indice_list, value_list in zip(top_k_indices, top_k_values):
...     for indice, value in zip(indice_list, value_list):
...         d[indice] += value

>>> d
Counter({3: 0.8, 5: 0.8, 2: 0.4, 1: 0.1})
# this is your expected result

# a counter is a kind of dict, but if you need a real dict:
>>> dict(d)
{1: 0.1, 3: 0.8, 5: 0.8, 2: 0.4}

# 3 indices with maximum values
>>> d.most_common(3)
[(3, 0.8), (5, 0.8), (2, 0.4)]
>>> sorted([indice for indice, value in d.most_common(3)])
[2, 3, 5]
```

Comment: Thank you.  This is a good way to do it in Python. I am looking for a tensorflow code. This is a part of my deep learning  model.